# php/mysqli Validating Form Input to Inserting to Displaying. Security at each step?

Tags: php, forms, validation, mysqli

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find a good thorough answer to explain each step of this process. It's all in bits and parts that are very hard to put together.

I'd like to know when and what security measures to use throughout the process of:

1. Form Validation
2. Preparing Data for Database Insertion
3. Displaying Data from Database

   1. Form Validation: Should I be using the raw form input for this, or do I need to escape anything BEFORE attempting to validate it?

Example: Do I need the "mysqli_real_escape_string" here or does it belong only at step 2 below?

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailERR = "* Required";
} else { 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailERR = "* Invalid email"; 
        }
    }
```

2. Once input is verified using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, is it safe to send it "as is" to the database using prepared statement, or does it need further validation or sanitation?
3. When I want to display data from the database, can I just use "htmlspecialchars($fieldData)" and nothing else for it to display safely in the users' browsers? For example, if I used mysqli_real_escape_string before inserting it, is there something else I need to do to re-format it for display when I get it from the database?

From what I've learned so far, I'm hoping the answer is:

1. Use raw input for validation
2. Use mysqli_real_escape_string with prepared statements when inserting records
3. Use htmlspecialchars to display data from database

...but I'm new to this, so please let me know if I'm missing anything...

Of course my concern is defending against attacks here... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Form validation: you should use htmlspecialvars() right away when getting any $_POST['...'] values:

```
$email = htmlspecialvars($_POST['email']);
```

2)Preparing data for insertion: I recommend using PDO (and not mysqli). Most programmers would agree it is the better way to go forward with MySQL since it is more object oriented, and you wouldn't want to have to change all your code later on in the future. You already filtered your data in step once, so no need to do it again.

3) Since your data has been filtered before you even inserted it into the database, there is no need to filter it when retrieving this data to show to other users.

Hope that helps! Let me know if it did